# TableView Scrolls Over NavBar

Tags: ios, uitableview, navbar

When I scroll my TableView, it scrolls over my navigation bar (which I made without using the built in navigation bar for various reasons). See below:

Unscrolled:

[image]

Scrolled up:

[image]

How do I make it so that the TableView scrolls under the Navbar?

**SOLVED:**

I checked the "clips subviews" box for the table view to fix this problem.

Comment: Try using contentInset?

Comment: contentInset only changes the initial position of the TableView, not its scrolling behavior.

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like there may be an issue with your view hierarchy. Now, I assume that you built your own navigation bar by subclassing UINavigationBar.

In order to get the kind of behavior you need, you should have the following:

1. UIWindow's rootViewController is an instance of UINavigationController.
2. UINavigationController.navigationBar = your subclass of UINavigationBar.
3. UINavigationController.viewControllers[0] = UITableViewController
4. The UITableViewController.view = your UITableView

Comment: I am not using a UITableViewController though. I did this all with a ViewController, a UIView, and a TableView. I put the UIView at the top and the TableView below the UIView. So I don't understand why the TableView seems to be scrolling beyond its borders as they are set in the ViewController (explicitly below the UIView so that the top of the TableView touches the bottom of the UIView).

Comment: You do not need to use the UITableViewController, as long as your ViewController makes use of the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols. What you should have is the UINavigation controller, which points to your navigation bar for its navigationBar property and has your ViewController in its viewControllers array.

Comment: No I don't have a UINavigation controller because I found it was too difficult to get it to look like I wanted (with the arrow and "home" text being the left button). My question is basically how do I get the tableview to take up a space that is smaller than the entire page? I made its width and height such that it should not cover the view above but when it is scrolled, is does cover that view. How do I make the view always be on top of the table view?

Comment: Ok. If you are using interface builder, it should be as simple as resizing your navigator bar view on the top and the tableView below it. Programatically, you should be able to resize the tableview: `(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, w, h)];
}` The only other thing I can think of that you could be experiencing is an issue with the way you have set [the constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html), since they could override any default sizes you set.